# Creating a Trigger To Delete Records

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I have a table which we can call decks. Decks has an id used as its primary key along with some other attributes. The cards table contains a foreign key reference to the deck id and has a primary key of cardid as well. Another table exists called answers where its foreign key is the cardid.

So in order to delete from decks, the database requires I delete from answers first, then cards, and then finally from decks.

I would like to create a trigger which takes care of the first and second delete so that I only have to specify a delete statement from the decks table to completely destroy a deck.

Below is an example PostgreSQL trigger I've found, but I am not sure if its even possible to do what I am asking as I can find no examples online of anyone creating a trigger this way.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION autoCalculate() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
        BEGIN

        IF NEW.wins < 0 THEN
                RAISE EXCEPTION 'Wins cannot be negative';
        END IF;

        IF(OLD.wins <> NEW.wins_ OR (OLD.losses <> NEW.losses) THEN
                NEW.Winning_Percentage := calc_winning_percentage(NEW.Wins, NEW.Losses);
        END IF

        RETURN NEW;
        END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DROP TRIGGER update_winning_percentage ON standings;
CREATE TRIGGER update_winning_percentage BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON standings
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE autoCalculate();
```

If anyone has knowledge to do this, if they could nudge me in the right direction or provide an example of how to do this I'd be grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your [foreign key](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) definitions use ON DELETE CASCADE and it will take care of this for you

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres 8.2 you can specify `On Delete Casacde` when you define your foreign key relationships.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/ddl-constraints.html